# Windows application to batch convert PDF into HTML?

Tags: windows, pdf, html

For someone who doesn't have much computer skills, I need to find a simple solution for Windows to share presentations. Ideally, it should be GUI-based since I fear CLI will be a bit too hard to use.

1. Some of the presentations are in PowerPoint, Word, or LibreOffice
   Write, so must first be converted into PDF
2. All the presentations must then be made web-compatible, ie. turned into HTML and JPG, with a clear separation so readers know where each presentation starts and ends
3. The whole thing must be uploaded to a web server through FTP into a new directory to keep things tidy
4. Finally, the user shares the URL to this set of presentations.

If you've been through this before, what tool would you recommend?

Thank you.

Comment: At least open office (my Libre Office version currently doesn't work but should probably be valid here as well) can save as HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, the tool should be able to batch convert files, since a conference contains multiple files, often in different formats.

Comment: Looks like that with microsoft word it should be possible as well (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/bshukla/2010/07/28/how-to-convert-a-word-document-to-other-formats-using-powershell/). Further good starting point might be to google e.g. batch convert word to html

Comment: Converting PowerPower or LibreOffice or PDF documents to HTML is a tricky business. If your goal is just to distribute the presentations electronically, why not let people download the original files?

Comment: Too complicated for most users. I want to turn a PDF into HTML so they can just view it in a browser. The web = HTML, not PDF. I'll try to find a way. Thank you.